# Fast Grid Search for Holt-Winters alpha/beta/gamma parameters

Tags: python, optimization, grid-search, hyperparameters, holtwinters

I have implemented the Holt-Winters model via Statsmodels in my script and I can make predictions with it but I manually set the alpha beta and gamma hyperparameters. According to you, what would be the fastest way to get the ideal values for those parameters with my dataset and how to implement it? Is there any auto optimization for the Holt-Winters just like Auto Arima? You can find my Python code below:

sample file:

https://ufile.io/e3zqs

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\YannickLECROART\\Documents\\Python\\temprennes.xlsx", index_col=0)

df = df.fillna(0)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# our guessed parameters
alpha = 0.4
beta = 0.2
gamma = 0.01

# initialise model
ets_model = ExponentialSmoothing(df_data, trend='add', seasonal='add', 
seasonal_periods=12)
ets_fit = ets_model.fit(smoothing_level=alpha, smoothing_slope=beta,
smoothing_seasonal=gamma)

# forecast p hours ahead
p_ahead = 12
yh = ets_fit.forecast(p_ahead)
```

Comment: As you tagged, I think the best solution will be a [grid search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV), which can also be parallelized via the `n_jobs` argument.

Comment: Could you show me how to implement it in my code? Thanks in adavance.

Comment: [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search) is a quite extensive tutorial on how to use this grid search. Give it a try, it should be easy to use.

Comment: Nope, Grid Search would not be the best, I think, because it will only try some discrete values of your choice. You can try an optimization approach instead. I.e. look here for complete implementation details https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Yorko/mlcourse_open/blob/master/jupyter_english/topic09_time_series/topic9_part1_time_series_python.ipynb?flush_cache=true